# Swift iOS 8, first value of NSDictionary

Tags: iphone, swift, ios8

I have NSDictionary, I know it only has one key and one value, how can I directly get the first value from it?

thanks,

Answer (score 28, accepted):

If you have a Swift `Dictionary` and you know you have exactly 1 key/value pair you can do this:

```
var dict = ["aaa":"bbb"]
let v = dict.values.first!
```

If you have more than 1 key/value pair then there is no "first" value since dictionaries are unordered.  If you have no key/value pairs this will crash.

If you have an `NSDictionary`, you can use `allValues.first!`, but you'll have to cast the result because the value will be an `AnyObject`:

```
var dict:NSDictionary = ["aaa":"bbb"]
let v = dict.allValues.first! as! String
```

or:

```
let v = dict.allValues[0] as! String
```

Comment: Ancient answer, it's hard to believe Swift was such a mess back in the day

Answer (score 8):

Cast to a Swift Dictionary if it isn't one already. Then use the `values` property, cast to an Array, and get index 0.

```
let v = Array(myDictionary.values)[0]
```

Comment: Be warned, however, that if you have more than one key-value pair, there is no "first value" - a dictionary is unordered. This trick works only because you know for certain that the `count` is 1.

Comment: `let v = dict.values.first!`

Comment: @vacawama Go ahead and give that as an answer! Excellent.